# Styles getting lost using document.execCommand("insertorderedlist") in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, execcommand

The following snippet loses custom styles on Chrome, but not on Firefox:

```js
    document.getElementById( 'run' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
      document.execCommand("insertorderedlist");
    } );
```

```html
  <div contenteditable="true">
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">line 1</span></p>
    <p><span style="font-style: italic;">line 2</span></p>
    <p><span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">line 3</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <button id="run">Select the above text and click me</button>
```

Is there a known workaround for this? I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to get the style of the selections common ancestor (which, in this case, is a text node, so you'll have to get the parentNode), and apply it to the new selections common ancestor:

```js
document.getElementById( 'run' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            let selection = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if (selection.startContainer.parentNode.tagName === 'SPAN') {
              let startNode = selection.startContainer.parentNode.parentNode;
              let endNode = selection.endContainer.parentNode.parentNode;
              let styles = [startNode.firstChild.style.cssText];
              while(startNode && !startNode.isEqualNode(endNode)) {
                  startNode = startNode.nextElementSibling || startNode.nextSibling;
                  styles.push(startNode.firstChild.style.cssText);
              }
              document.execCommand("insertorderedlist");
              selection = sel.getRangeAt(0);
              startNode = selection.startContainer.parentNode;
              endNode = selection.endContainer.parentNode;
              newNodes = [startNode];
              while(startNode && !startNode.isEqualNode(endNode)) {
                  startNode = startNode.nextElementSibling || startNode.nextSibling;
                  newNodes.push(startNode);
              }
              for (var i = 0; i < newNodes.length; i++) {
                 newNodes[i].style = styles[i];
              }
            } else {
              if (sel.rangeCount) {
                  let ancestor = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode;
                  document.execCommand("insertorderedlist");
                  sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.style = ancestor.style.cssText;
              }
          }
        }
        
    } );
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">line 1</span></p>
    <p><span style="font-style: italic;">line 2</span></p>
    <p><span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">line 3</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <button id="run">Select the above text and click me</button>
```

Comment: On Chrome, this code doesn't work when you select all three lines. :/

Comment: made some changes, still a bug with only selecting two lines, but should be enough to get you started